# Disable jgrowl notifications in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, jgrowl

I'm developping a Wordpress site and would like to disable the JGrowl notifications that appear every time a product page is displayed. They show an information that we believe is not relevant to customers, so it would be better if it was hidden.

But I cannot find where to disable or hide it. By the moment, I've added a CSS rule, but it would be better to disable it completely.

Thankyou very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
     $('#jGrowl').jGrowl('shutdown');
```

If you're using something other than the default container for your jGrowl notification you will have to update that selector accordingly.

Comment: There is not a way that doesn't need to edit the template? I'd rather to configure it from Prestashop's control panel...